# How to create a function that returns another function, encompassing a given argument implicitly in C?

Tags: c, closures, function-pointers

I want to have a function that returns a function that is called **without** an argument, even though the original function must be called **with** an argument. The argument is passed to the first function and will be implicitly used each time a call to the returned function is made.

I am aware of function pointers in C but I don't know if they can be used in such a way. I know how to do this in python as shown in the following sample code :

```py
def foo(some_argument):
    print(some_argument)

def register_callback(function, argument):
    def new_function():
        function(argument)

    return new_function

bar = register_callback(foo,"bar")

bar()
```

From what I read, this way is not possible in C because we can't nest function definitions. Is this possible and if so what would be the proper way to do it?

Comment: It's not possible in C because C has no way of creating new functions at run time.  It would be straightforward in C++, though (especially with Boost).

Comment: This is an example of a closure in Python.  You can do something similar in C by storing the argument(s) in a structure and then passing the structure address to a wrapper function.  That would get you down to one argument, but you can't eliminate the arguments completely.  Doing so would require dynamic function creation (or at least argument binding), which C doesn't support.

Comment: `The argument ... will be implicitly used each time a call to the returned function is made`, and the returned function `is called without an argument`? How is the argument used if it's not used?

Comment: @SteveSummit: I"m thinking the first function returns a structure containing a function pointer and the argument; so other code can call the function (via. the function pointer) and also do whatever is supposed to happen with the argument.

Comment: @Brendan wouldn't the function call still need 1 argument, i.e. a pointer to the struct containing the "real" arguments?

Comment: @TomKarzes — what about the Foreign Function Interface library [`libffi`](https://github.com/libffi/libffi)? However, you still can't create functions at runtime in C. You can load shared objects (dynamic link libraries) and call functions from those — as long as you know the correct calling sequence — and you _could_ also run the compiler to create a shared object that's loaded dynamically, but that's pretty contorted. But `libffi` can help. It still isn't trivial.  So, this isn't wholly disagreeing with you, Tom. If this feature is important to the OP, use a language that supports closures.

Comment: @SteveSummit C++ does not have that ability either.

Comment: @Acorn Well,  [functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses) come pretty close, and I think they'd let the OP do what he's trying to do.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yeah, but that is not creating functions at runtime. The answer below from Eric is the same thing as a functor, in C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not familiar with libffi.  Does it support dynamic argument binding?  If so, I assume the user has to explicitly free the memory associated with the binding when done with it (or explicitly provide the memory to libffi when creating the binding).

Comment: I've not used `libffi` either, Tom, but I understand that it can be used to dynamic argument binding pretty thoroughly.  Using its interface is portable; it's implementation is potentially different on each platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About all you can do in C is create a record (a `struct`) containing both the function pointer and the argument to pass and then use that record as the “thing” that is called, with the assistance of a wrapper function that does the actual calling.

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef int SomeType;   //  Sample type for demonstration.


//  Define a record to hold a function pointer and the argument we want to pass.
typedef struct
{
    void (*Function)(SomeType); //  Function to call.
    SomeType Argument;  //  Argument to pass.
} Closure;


//  Define some sample functions.
static void A(SomeType x) { printf("Called %s(%d).\n", __func__, x); }
static void B(SomeType x) { printf("Called %s(%d).\n", __func__, x); }


//  Define a function that returns a closure.
static Closure foo(int Which, SomeType x)
{
    return (Closure) { .Function = Which & 1 ? B : A, .Argument = x };
}


//  Define a function to call a closure.
static void Call(Closure C) { C.Function(C.Argument); }


int main(void)
{
    Closure a = foo(0, 34);
    Closure b = foo(1, 79);
    Call(a);
    Call(b);
}
```

Output:

```
Called A(34).
Called B(79).
```

Comment: It is always worth noting that when you bodge up high-level language constructs in c like this you are simply exposing a possible way that the same features could be implemented "under the hood" of more expressive languages. They just do the bookkeeping for you.